# how to draw a matrix image with R

Tags: r

I'm trying to draw a similar a matrix image like this using a known matrix. in this image each square represent the frequency of the corresponding number in vertical axis, and darker color square means high frequency of that number.  For example, my known matrix could be generate as

```
Ture   <- rep(8, 100)
PA     <- rep(7, 100) 
ED     <- sample(6:8, 100, replace = T)
ER     <- rep(0, 100)
IC1    <- sample(1:2, 100, replace = T)
NE     <- sample(3:4, 100, replace = T)
BCV    <- sample(5:7, 100, replace = T)
Oracle <- sample(5:6, 100, replace = T)

M <- rbind(Ture, PA, ED, ER, IC1, NE, BCV, Oracle)
```

Thanks very much!

[image: Matrix image]

Comment: Do you mean `image(M)`?

Comment: Or perhaps `image(M, axes = F); axis(1, at = seq(0, 1, length.out = nrow(M)), labels = rownames(M))`?

Comment: Yes, I mean the image of matrix M. But I want the vertical axis to give the corresponding number in the column, like 8, 6, or 0 ect., and the darker color represent the frequency of that number in the column. Thanks very much for your comments! @MauritsEvers

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment above, you can do the following

```
image(M, axes = F, col = rev(gray.colors(12, start = 0, end = 1)))
axis(1, at = seq(0, 1, length.out = nrow(M)), labels = rownames(M))
axis(2, at = seq(0, 1, length.out = 11), labels = seq(0, 100, length.out = 11))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for replying! Yes, I mean the image of matrix M. But I want the vertical axis to give the corresponding number in the column, like 8, 6 ect., and the darker color represent the frequency of that number in the column.

Comment: @ZhenhaoGong ??? That's exactly what is shown. The darker the shading the higher the frequency as per your original request. Values on the y axis denote columns.

Comment: In your image, the darker the shading the higher the number not frequency, such as using black to represent 8, white represeting 0 ect. You can check the example image I posted under my question. I don't know how to draw it. Thanks very much!

Comment: @ZhenhaoGong I don't understand what you're after. What "frequency" are you referring to. I've used *your* sample data to colour the rectangles. If that's not what you want, please provide **representative sample data** and/or a better explanation. Please add this information in the main post, not in the comments.